# table.rows.length is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

I have below script in my html page,

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
```

Its working fine in IE8. But when I use IE11, it is not returning exact row. instead it is just returning "0". But actual row size is "1".

What is the code needs to be replace to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, given a reference to the `table` element is to use `querySelectorAll` to find the `tr` within the `tbody`:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
  console.log(table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").length);
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I got another problem, may be I should post separately. I have a html table with name 'myTable', I get rows by myTable.rows, when I try to get myTable.rows.length, I get error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I don't understand, when I try direcly on Chrome console, myTabl;e.rows.length gives me correct result. then why I am not able to use myTabl;e.rows.length within the function? This is I am trying on 2021 August>..

Comment: @k.b if you have a separate question you should definitely post it as its own question